# Sharepoint request digest value cross-domain

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'm building a webapplication on NodeJS and ExpressJs where i am trying to upload documents to a Sharepoint Online library through the Sharepoint REST Api.

I'm able to authenticate and create and update list items. I'm using `node-sp-auth` to authenticate and `express-request` to make http requests.

In order to access the Sharepoint REST api i'm using the `FormDigestValue` in my header.

Header:

```
Headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
Headers['X-RequestDigest'] = FormDigestValue;
Headers['Accept'] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
Headers['X-HTTP-Method'] = "POST";
```

This is **working fine** when i try to create/update list items in a custom list. But when i try to upload a document i receive the following error:

```
body: '{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":
{"lang":"en-US","value":"There is no app context to execute this request."}}}' } }
```

The url i am using for upload:

```
siteurl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?" +
        "@TargetSite='" + siteurl + "'" +
        "&@TargetLibrary='" + libraryName + "'" +
        "&@TargetFileName='" + fileName + "'";
```

The post request:

```
request.post({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    headers: uploadHeaders,
    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
    body: fileData,
})
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this format instead for the post:

```
url: url,
type: 'POST',
data: fileData,
processData: false,
headers: { 
    'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'X-RequestDigest': digest,
    'Content-Length': fileData.byteLength 
}
```

If you don't have a RequestDigest already call _api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/contextinfo

Comment: I think that helped. Now I'm getting `"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."` I'm certain that I have the right permissions.